# Python pandas: How to get multiple subsets of dataframe efficiently based on id column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'C1': ['1A', '1B', '1C', '2A', '2B'], 'C2': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})
print(df)

   id  C1   C2
0   1  1A  100
1   1  1B  200
2   1  1C  300
3   2  2A  400
4   2  2B  500
```

From this dataframe, how do I get multiple subsets for each value of the 'id', like this?

```
   id  C1   C2
0   1  1A  100
```

```
   id  C1   C2
0   1  1A  100
1   1  1B  200
```

```
   id  C1   C2
0   1  1A  100
1   1  1B  200
2   1  1C  300
```

```
   id  C1   C2
0   2  2A  400
```

```
   id  C1   C2
0   2  2A  400
1   2  2B  500
```

I can write a for loop like below.

```
for id in df['id'].unique().tolist():
    df1 = df[df['id'] == id]
    for i in range(len(df1) + 1):
        df1 = df1.head(i)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this, because the dataframe I have has thousands of values in the 'id' column.

I tried using df.apply, but it works only on 1 row at a time (with axis=1).

My final objective is to end up with a dataframe as below (where C2 is the sum of the values in C2 column of the subset dataframes).

```
    id  1A  1B  1C  2A  2B  C2
0    1   1   0   0   0   0  100
0    1   1   1   0   0   0  300
0    1   1   1   1   0   0  600
1    2   0   0   0   1   0  400
1    2   0   0   0   1   1  900
```

If I go with the for loop approach, I can do a groupy 'id', sum 'C2' column and crosstab on the subset dataframe obtained in the inner for loop. Then I can do finally pd.concat all the subset crosstab results. But I don't know how to do this more efficiently. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, there is no need to create all of these subsets yourself because you can do "cumulative" calculations to accomplish what you need.

C2 is the result of a **cumulative sum** (`cumsum`) within each 'ID'. Your dummy columns are the result of `pd.get_dummies` and then a **cumulative max** (`cummax`) within each group group (credit to @Ben.T). Join the calculations with `concat` to get your result and use `groupby` + `ngroup` to label each ID for your desired Index.

```
# Dummies for C1
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.C1)
df1 = df1.groupby(df['id']).cummax()

# Join, ID from df, dummies from df1 and cumsum
df1 = pd.concat([df['id'], df1, df.groupby('id')['C2'].cumsum()], axis=1)

# Create your index, breaks alignment of df and df1 from this point on     
df1.index = df1.groupby(df['id'], sort=False).ngroup()
```

---

```
print(df1)

   id  1A  1B  1C  2A  2B   C2
0   1   1   0   0   0   0  100
0   1   1   1   0   0   0  300
0   1   1   1   1   0   0  600
1   2   0   0   0   1   0  400
1   2   0   0   0   1   1  900
```

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thanks a lot!